# Significant slower processing as Set size goes beyond 500.000

Tags: java, set, hashset

I'm not used to working with really large datasets and I'm kind of stumped here.

I have the following code:

```
private static Set<String> extractWords(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    String strLine;
    String tempWord;
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
    Utils utils = new Utils();
    int articleCounter = 0;
    while(((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)){
        if(utils.lineIsNotCommentOrLineChange(strLine)){
            articleCounter++;
            System.out.println("Working article : " + utils.getArticleName(strLine) + " *** Article #" + articleCounter + " of 3.769.926");
            strLine = utils.removeURLs(strLine);
            strLine = utils.convertUnicode(strLine);
            String[] temp = strLine.split("\\W+");
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
                tempWord = temp[i].trim().toLowerCase();
                if(utils.validateWord(tempWord)){
                    words.add(tempWord);
                    System.out.println("Added word " + tempWord + " to list");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

This basically gets a huge text file from the BufferedReader where each line of text is a text from an article. I want to make a list of unique words in this text file, but there are 3.769.926 articles in there, so the word count is quite immense.

From what I understand about Sets, or specifically HashSets, this should be the man for the job so to speak. Everything runs quite smoothly at first, but after 500.000 articles it starts slowing down a bit. When it reaches 700.000 its beginning to get slow enough that it basically stops for a second of two before going on again. There's a bottleneck here somewhere, and I can't see what it is..

Any ideas?

Comment: Hashsets are backed by hashmaps, once you grow to a large value it has to start doing deep copies of it's data in order to make sure the collisions don't become ridiculous. High collision counts will eventually turn your constant time performing collection into performing linearly. IF you size the table correctly it will operate more efficiently with the proper trade off of memory and performance smoothness

Comment: @GregGiacovelli Just to make sure I understand your suggestion; He should use the HashSet(int initialCapacity) constructor, where the initialCapacity is quite high? Possibly even use Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: You got to figure it out for your needs and what works best. Not sure how big these objects are, but it might be worth also change the loadfactor to not be as aggressive too

Comment: As others have said, you might not want this all in memory ;)

Comment: Here is some useful information about Set implementations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/set.html

Comment: Since all the other comments here are related to the hashing, just to add a completely unrelated issue is it possible you're leaving all these articles in memory and GC-ing? I see the extractWords from the bufferedReader but it's impossible to see what you're doing with the reader when you're done. Are you closing the underlying resources?

Comment: @SteveB. The bufferedreader is closed in the method calling extractWords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the issue you may be facing is that a Hash Table(set or map) has to be backed by a fixed number of entries it can hold. So your first declaration may have a table able to hold 16 entries. Putting aside things like load factors, once you tried to put 17 entries into the table, it has to grow to accommodate more entries to prevent collisions, so Java will expand it for you.

This expansion includes creating a new table with `2 * previousSize` entries, then copying over the old entries. So if you are constantly expanding, you may end up hitting an area, like 
524,288 where it will have to grow, but it will create a new table able to handle 1,048,576 entries, but it will have to copy over the entire previous table.

If you don't mind the extra look up time, you might think about using a `TreeSet` instead of a `HashSet`. You lookups will now be logarithmic time, but a `Tree` doesn't have a pre-allocated table and can grow dynamically easily. Either use this, or declare the size of your `HashSet` so it won't grow dynamically.

Comment: Also gc may be happening frequently and contributing to slowness. Increase the heap size to several GB and make sure to run the 64-bit version of Java.

Comment: Correct. I was thinking from a pure programming standpoint, but JVM optimizations can also be made to speed this up.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly for that sort of scale you are better off going over to a database. You can embed Derby inside your application if you don't want to use a separate one.

Their indexing systems are optimised for this sort of scale, and while HashSet etc will cope if you massage them right you are better off using the right tool for it.

Comment: ... and kill the speed by writing each word to database ?!

Comment: @AmitSharma you can buffer DB writes into a batch, which will actually go pretty fast. It will also allow you to do the writing in a separate thread while refilling the next buffer.

Comment: And if you are writing to a Derby database its all inside the same Java process as well, so fast.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by TheSageMage, the HashSet implementation will constantly resize the underlying HashMap as the data grows. There are a couple of ways of getting around that: initial capacity and load factor. You can set both by using the 2-arg constructor: [HashSet(int, float)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28int,%20float%29). If you know the approximate number of words you are going to need, you can set the initial capacity to be bigger than that number. This will make smaller maps work a little slower, but will prevent dramatic slow-down for larger maps. The load factor is how full the map must get before increasing the underlying size rehashing. Since this is a relatively time-consuming operation for large maps, you may want to set it to a large fraction, say 0.9. If your initial capacity was set so that you may exceed it but will never exceed twice that size, a large load factor will guarantee that you rehash only once and as late as possible.